# No idea what SpatiaLite is, and how to get it

Tags: django, macos, geodjango, spatialite

I'm trying to get SpatiaLite, because I need it for this https://pythonrepo.com/repo/caioariede-django-location-field--python-django-utilities

I have read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/gis/install/spatialite/), but no idea what all that stuff means.

How do I install SpatiaLite on MacOS?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the brew package manager? If you have it you could try this:

`brew install spatialite-tools`

I also managed to find [this article](https://medium.com/@carusot42/installing-and-loading-spatialite-on-macos-28bf677f0436)

Comment: Is spatialite-tools spatialite? I followed the article, but my sqlite3 didn't have .load, so I got stuck following it.